# How to convert a stream that contains a pdf to text?

Tags: c#, pdf, stream, azure-functions, pdfsharp

I'm working in an azure function to extract the text of a pdf file. I want to convert a stream (received by an azure blob storage containing a pdf) into a pdf so I can use the code of [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141143/c-sharp-extract-text-from-pdf-using-pdfsharp).

```
public static class PdfSharpExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> ExtractText(this PdfPage page)
    {       
        var content = ContentReader.ReadContent(page);      
        var text = content.ExtractText();
        return text;
    }   

    public static IEnumerable<string> ExtractText(this CObject cObject)
    {   
        if (cObject is COperator)
        {
            var cOperator = cObject as COperator;
            if (cOperator.OpCode.Name== OpCodeName.Tj.ToString() ||
                cOperator.OpCode.Name == OpCodeName.TJ.ToString())
            {
                foreach (var cOperand in cOperator.Operands)
                    foreach (var txt in ExtractText(cOperand))
                        yield return txt;   
            }
        }
        else if (cObject is CSequence)
        {
            var cSequence = cObject as CSequence;
            foreach (var element in cSequence)
                foreach (var txt in ExtractText(element))
                    yield return txt;
        }
        else if (cObject is CString)
        {
            var cString = cObject as CString;
            yield return cString.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: which kind of stream do you have?

Comment: and whats in the stream?

Comment: So your actual goal isn't to convert it to a pdf page, but to extract the text of the pdf stored on the stream?

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI System.IO.Stream

Comment: @BugFinder a pdf file

Comment: @Innat3 exactly

Comment: Well then in theory you should just need to write it to a file

Comment: so you want to create pdf from stream?

Comment: return the PDF file from your site and the browser should attempt to open it with a compatible extension or plug-in. It may default to downloading it instead, depends on your browser's configuration.

Comment: You didn't event specify your application platform, different platform have different approaches. Add more details to your post so the community won't have to guess its way to help you.

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI yes, so I can use the extension methods I linked to extract the text

Comment: @jegtugado edited the post. Hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as I understand it you need to create a PDF from the stream and then use the PDF to read the content.

So firstly we need to create a PDF from a MemoryStream, but wait we only have a Stream so we need to convert it to a MemoryStream like so:

```cs
public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{    
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
    int read;
    while((read = input.Read (buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write (buffer, 0, read);
    }
}

// Create MemoryStream
var ms = new MemoryStream();
CopyStream(streamFromDatabase, ms);

// Create PDF from MemoryStream
var pdf = PdfReader.Open(ms);
```

And now we can read the text from it like so:

```cs
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var page in pdf.Pages)
{
     sb.Append(string.Join("", page.ExtractText().ToArray()));
}
```

Comment: I used what you said and the sb returns this `ExtractTextFromPDF.PdfSharpExtensions+<ExtractText>d__1`
(**ExtractTextFromPDF** is the name of the project, **PdfSharpExtensions** is the name of the class where I have the extension method to extract the text)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `var pdf = PdfReader.Open(ms);
` and inspect `pdf` and `ms`. What are they?

Comment: `ms`  appears to be null and have a read and write timeout. 
The pdf has the  author, creation date and other data right, but I can't find the content. `AcroForm` is null, I don't know if that helps.

Comment: What is `AcroForm`? Also `ms` can't be null, it's probably just empty after converting to a pdf. Is the `pdf` variable correct? Does it have pages and such?

Comment: `AcroForm` is a pdf property. It does have the page count correctly. I don't know what properties should I look for.

Comment: Don't use the AcroFrom Property, just directly iterate over the `Pages` property and pass each value

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write it correctly so it led into a confusion. ´Acroform´ is  property and I just mentioned it is null, it has nothing else inside it and no correlation with pages. I debugged the pdf variable and then the individual page but I can't fins any text property or something similar.

Comment: Should the `Stream` property of pdf.Pages have the text? Currently it is null

Comment: No. I don't where the text is, I simply know that `Pages` is a Enumerable of PdfPage. So we can iterate (foreach) over the Pages and pass each individual page to the ExtractText Method (page.ExtractText). Wha I just saw now is that ExtractText method returns an IEnumerable of Strings so we need to join them togheter. I updated my answer

Comment: That was the problem. It worked lights out. Thank you!